# Can't uninstall Django app

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I can't uninstall Django app. I've removed every occurence of the application in my code, removed all models and urls. Then, I removed parts of app from `settings.py` but it raises error when I remove them for `settings.py`.

It has probably something to do with migrations but I don't get it since all migrations alre already migrated...

Here is a traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x038E6130>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 168, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 314, in build_graph
    parent = self.check_key(parent, key[0])
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 176, in check_key
    raise ValueError("Dependency on unknown app: %s" % key[0])
ValueError: Dependency on unknown app: quiz
```

Comment: dump your db and start project with empty db.  Then reload data perhaps

Comment: If they're still in the migrations then you haven't removed all references to the app. one of your migrations will still rely on that application

Comment: There are many miration files with this app's attributes occurences. Should I remove these occurences? Is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with migrations files which contained uninstalled app's referencies.

This is probably not a best way to do that but it worked:

1. I backuped all migrations from all applications (to be able to do rollback)
2. Removed all migrations
3. makemigrations and migrate
4. it works

Comment: Generally, it's probably better to write a custom migration to identify removing the model, but what you did will do the trick